# Validate Textfield after each character entered

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

I have searched for an answer but cant find an answer related to this.

I am trying to validate every input into a textfield but not sure how to go about it, the idea is to check a username exist on a server so I would assume I need to post to the server each time something is entered and if success do whatever.

Could someone please advise I would be grateful.

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765654/textfield-validation-with-regular-expression. Really impressive answer.. It helped me.Gud luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` with `UIControlEventValueChanged` (e.g: `[textfield addTarget:self action:@selector(usernameChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged`). This will inform you AFTER the text changes (so when you receive `usernameChanged:` you'll have the last modifications).

It's probably a good idea that instead of sending a request to the server each time the username changes you either send a request when the textfield looses caption or when  some time passes from the last change (you can use a `NSTimer` for this).

You should use a single asynchronous request. If the request is active and the textfield is edited again you should cancel the request and set it to nil  (since there's no reason to check the old username). If the request succeeds show up an icon, or whatever you want to do when you get the result from the server.

**Edit:**
Not sure if `UIControlEventValueChanged` worked on previous versions of iOS or if it was a mistake from my side, but it doesn't seem to work any longer. `UIControlEventEditingChanged` should be used instead.

Comment: Thanks alot mate for your help I will look into this also seems the best way to go! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Implement the delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to be informed about every change to the text. Return `YES` or `NO` depending on whether you want to accept the change or not.

It is probably a very bad idea to ask the server for approval of every single key press since that would create an intolerable lag and lead to a very bad user experience.

Comment: Hi Ole Thanks for your reply, could you provide some sort of example for me please im quite new to all of this. Thanks

Comment: No, I won't write the code for you since I don't think that's good for learning. The documentation for `UITextField` and the method I listed above should help you.

Answer (score 2):

What Ole is saying is absolutely correct.  I'll just give you an example of what he's saying.

First conform your class to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.  Then make sure in `viewDidLoad` (or similar) that you set the delegate to your class:

```
myTextField.delegate = self;
```

Next you can implement the method that Ole was mentioning. However, in your case you're not validating whether the user *can* enter anything or not, you just want to know *what* he entered so you can validate it online.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    [self verifyTheUserWithUsername:[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]];
    //do your appropriate check here
    return YES; //we allow the user to enter anything
}
```

Comment: `[self verifyTheUserWithUsername:textField.text];` doesn't work very well in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, since it informs of an edit before it's been applied to the textfield.

Comment: @SirL0fty: I would definately go with the suggestions mentioned by Ole and babbidi.  Checking the server after each key press will really bog your app down.  Starting a timer and invalidating it if another key is pressed would definitely be the way to go.  I'd suggest something like one second as the interval for a check.

Comment: @babbidi you could do something like this:'[self verifyTheUserWithUsername:[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string]];'since the paramter 'string' is the new input typed by the user.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks for mentioning that, I forgot that the textfield's string hasn't been updated before this method is called.  I'll edit my answer for future reference.

Comment: Maybe you have to comment the NSString *string=textField.text;?

Comment: actually you should use `[textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string]` because it handles inserts in the middle of the string and replacements of parts of the string too