# UITextField validation error

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, validation, uitextfield

I am trying to validate three UITextFields and none of the textfields are accepting more than 11 characters. If I type the 12th character, my textfield turns red and I can't go to the next field to type.

I had a little help from this link [TextField Validation With Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765654/textfield-validation-with-regular-expression) with validation but now I can't seem to understand why are all my textfields not accepting more than 11 characters?

```
- (BOOL)validateInputWithString:(NSString *)aString
{
    NSString* regularExpression = @""; 

    if (aString == self.ipAddress.text) {
        regularExpression = @"^(([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])\\.){3}([01]?\\d\\d?|2[0-4]\\d|25[0-5])$";        
    } else if (aString == self.username.text) {
         regularExpression = @"^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$";
    } else if (aString == self.password.text) {
         regularExpression = @"^[^\\s\\r\\n][0-9a-zA-Zk\\r\\n@!#\\$\\^%&*()+=\\-\\[\\]\\\\\\';,\\.\\/\\{\\<>\\?\\s]*$"; 
    }

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern: regularExpression
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error %@", error);
    }

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:aString
                                                        options:0
                                                          range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])];

    if([self.ipAddress.text length]>0 && [self.username.text length]>0 && [self.password.text length]>0)
    {
        enableLogin = YES;

    }
    return numberOfMatches > 0;
}

- (void)validateInputCallback:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    UITextField* atextField = (UITextField *)[notification object];

    if ([self validateInputWithString:atextField.text]){ 

        //Turns the textfield green
        atextField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
        atextField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
        atextField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor greenColor]CGColor];
        atextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;

        } else {
        //Turns the textfield red
                atextField.layer.cornerRadius=8.0f;
                atextField.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
                atextField.layer.borderColor=[[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
                atextField.layer.borderWidth= 1.0f;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere you use `==` to compare strings is wrong, because you're comparing pointers not string contents and there will be copies of strings so pointers will be different. Change all of that to use `isEqualToString:`.

You shouldn't really determine logic based on the text you're trying to compare, you should choose the regex based on the text field that supplied the text.